# Category slug variable is not available when category url's are disabled

Tags: categories, slug

Just like the title states, the `slug` variable is not available when a category's url are disabled:

```
<select name="field-styles" id="field-styles" class="select">
    <option value="">Style</option>
    {% for style in craft.categories.group('productStyles').order('title') %}
    <option value="{{ style.slug }}">{{ style.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The snippet of code above works when the URL's are enabled for this category group. When disabled, the input `value` is blank.

Answer (score 1):

<s>That's by design, slugs are used for building the url to link to a specific element, in this case, a category.</s>

**Edit:** seems I was wrong on the above, see comment. Leaving the rest of the answer as using the ID offers a solution.

You'll have to use the id to refer to the category as value, like so:

```
<select name="field-styles" id="field-styles" class="select">
    <option value="">Style</option>
    {% for style in craft.categories.group('productStyles').order('title') %}
    <option value="{{ style.id }}">{{ style.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for the response. According to the makers it should work regardless. I believe in your case, the `url` variable would not be available: https://twitter.com/craftcms/status/902730869768691712

Comment: Than I'll gladly wait for someone else to chime in, I'll edit my answer. Still using the ID should work as a (temporary) solution